# My Styles are not registering

Tags: php

I am registering the stylesheet and scripts but It is not working please help me. What I am doing wrong

```
function theme_styles_and_scripts() {

   wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.6', 'all' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles_and_scripts' );
```

Comment: Hi, can you please specify what do you mean by 'Not working'? Aren't they outputted? Don't they take effect or ...?

Comment: yes they are not outputted

Comment: I have checked them by clicking ctrl + u

Comment: have you call wp_head() function in header.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons why it may not be working.

**Possibility-1:** You are adding the CSS file in a child theme. In that case, use the following CODE instead:

```
    function theme_styles_and_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.6', 'all' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles_and_scripts' );
```

[`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) returns the URL of your current theme (whether it is a child theme or not). On the other hand, [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) returns the parent theme URL if you are using a child theme & the current theme URL only if the active theme is not a child theme of another theme.

**Possibility-2:** You are not calling `wp_head()` anywhere in your theme's template files (usually `header.php`). However, if you are modifying any standard theme, then this is not the likely case, as any standard theme will not make this mistake.

**Other Possibilities:**

However, if you view HTML source & see that you are finding `bootstrap` in it, then perhaps another call to `wp_enqueue_style` with the same name is overriding it ([as suggested by this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/256674/110572)) or perhaps your CSS is being added, but some other CSS is overriding your CSS rules.

**How to Debug:**

An easy way to debug this issue is to create a simple CSS file with the following CSS CODE:

```
    body {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
```

Then save the CSS file in your theme's `css` folder with the name `wpse256672-style.css`.

Then use the following CODE in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
    function wpse256672_css_enqueue() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse256672_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/wpse256672-style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse256672_css_enqueue' );
```

Now if you reload the page after saving the above, you should see red background in your page. That means you don't have `Possibility-2` above, but perhaps `Possibility-1` or something else. Change CSS file name, `$handle` from `bootstrap` to something else, change version number, check if the file exists etc.

> Note: If you have cache plugin activated, clear cache first & then clear browser cache before doing the above tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third possibility, because, as `wp_enqueue_style` documentation says, the `$handle`param must be unique as it will not override an existing handle.
You should try and change the `$handle` param to something more specific.